# Transfering Access Data into an Excel template sheet behind a form event

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working on a new database in access to automate a lot of hand entry into Excel. Right now I have come to a point where Excel can graph and be distribeted easier than Access data.

I would like to place a button on a form that when pressed it will take data from Access and fill out an existing 'template' Excell sheet that has all the formulas and graph pulling from a set of cells. The data in Access (can be made into an sql query/record set in VBA) is just some totals, averages, and a YTD calculation and needs to be placed into a specific set of cells in an existing excel sheet and saved as a different one (as to not overwrite the template). It is only 13 x 5 cells of new data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. The Export will need to be meticulous though, because you already have a predefined range of cells you're using in Excel.

First step would be to get the data into the format you need - your SQL statement.
*Make sure this format will work for your template and is returning the correct data.*

Once this is done, you can write to your Excel file. This is the format.

```
expression.OutputTo(ObjectType, ObjectName, OutputFormat, OutputFile, AutoStart, TemplateFile, Encoding)
```

Here is an example:

```
Dim outputFileName As String
        outputFileName = "C:\WhereYouWantYourFileToGo "
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "YourQueryName", outputFileName, True

        MsgBox "Data exported to  WhereverYouExportedItTo.xlsx"
```

Note: When using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`, `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` is used for Excel 2010, the list of versions is [here](http://ss64.com/access/acspreadsheettype.html).

I'm assuming the rest will be handled by Excel.

Comment: I am getting a "Failure creating file" error (3436) when I execute.
I am trying it on a networked drive. I wish there was a better way to reply to answers. Thanks

Comment: Make sure your `outputFileName` is correct. Try exporting to your desktop first, as a simple test.

Comment: Yup, that was it. A new error arrose: This table contains cells that are outside the range provided. I also commented that out and got an error that excel cant open 'test.xlsx' becuase the file extension is not valid.  Thanks

Comment: Are you using Excel 2010? When you view your query results, if you copied the same data (# rows, # columns) and pasted it into your template, would it fit?

Comment: Well its later and I am at a different computer but here is what I have found. I am in Excel 2010 and used the proper spreadsheet type. I have found [a reference to this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793(v=office.15).aspx) and it says keave the range blank for export or it will fail. I removed it and now it is putting them into a second sheet on the xlsx document. Can I set the cells to look for those values? Is there a way to prevent the overwriting of my template? Thanks again and sorry for the delay.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, The spreadsheet is constantly update with every button press but prompts for save after the first time it is opened up until it is saved.

Comment: @Evan You figure it out?

Comment: Yup, Thanks for all your help!!! I am making it work by appending sheets named after the query (Access 2010 does this automatically in the method) and pulling the values from the appended sheets forward to the front with all the graphs and formating.
Thank you again